# Grails Map<String,Object> causes exception Integer cannot be cast to String

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

So, the problem I have is very strange per grails behaviour.

domain:-

```
public class Product {
    Group group  
    Map<String, Object> configuration 
...
...
}
```

below is the configuration passed while creating a new object.

```
configuration:[ emailAddress:null, **users:41**...]
```

users above is `Integer` but when I try saving the object as below.

```
instance.save flush: true
```

It says :-

```
Error java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
| Error     at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.StringTypeDescriptor.unwrap(StringTypeDescriptor.java:40)
| Error     at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:52)
| Error     at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:91)
```

One solution is to convert `integer` to `string` and then save it.It works as I tried this.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: could you use save with failOnError: true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is stated quite clearly in the Grails [manual](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#sets,ListsAndMaps) for you case: `In this case the key and value of the map MUST be strings.`

See that section ('Maps of Objects') for an alternate option (using a `hasMany` on your Map to define the value type).

Answer (score 1):

At some point, the values in your map need to get mapped to a column in your database. That database column has to have a specific data type. My *guess* is that since `Map<String, Object>` is pretty ambiguous as far as what it contains, that GORM just made that column a varchar and so it's expecting everything to be a string.

If you need to store ints as well as strings, you have two good options. This is assuming of course that you actually need to be using a map instead of normal properties.

#### Key/Value pairs

One would be to just use separate maps, one for each type. You can then use the static [mapping](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#ormdsl) block to specify how you want those mapped to columns in your database. Maps will probably end up as a table that stores key/value pairs. This is an anti-pattern in relational databases and can make querying that data difficult.

#### Use another database

[Document databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) tend to be a much better fit for highly variable data. [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) and [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) are both excellent databases. Each has it's own purpose, which is beyond the scope of this question, but one of the two is pretty likely to be a good fit for any document-store needs.